# Why is Excel 2016 resetting number formatting when a sum formula (upper-bounded with an offset) is used to sum a range?

Tags: excel-formula, sum, offset, number-formatting, excel-2016

As stated: assume range (A1:A30) contains values with many decimal places, but these values are formatted to show zero decimal places.

e.g. 123.456 reformatted to display as 124. 123.123 reformatted to display as 123

Assume that excel is in manual calculation mode.
Assume that the sum formula resides in A31.

When (A1:A30) is summed using an offset for the upper bound of the sum formula, the result's format inconsistently changes to include more than one decimal place. Sometimes it includes just 2 more decimal places, sometimes it includes so many that the cell becomes "############" because all of the decimals do not fit.

This does not happen when a normal sum formula is used to sum (A1:A30) and excel formats properly with no visible decimal places.

Excel will over-ride any user defined formatting if the formula is selected and the user hits enter to re-calculate.

What causes this behavior? Does excel use the underlying format of values in the range to auto-assign format for offset but not for sum?

TLDR;
SUM(A1:OFFSET(A31,-1,0)) formats decimals inconsistently e.g. 567.34894678921364
SUM(A1:A30) formats decimals as expected  e.g. 567
Why?

Comment: It appears that SUM makes an assumption and automatically changes the format of the cell to match the cells to which it refers when using a straight range.  But by using Offset, which resolves at the time of calculation, it does not know the full range at the time and as such does not change the format of the cell to match.  It is akin to using `DateValue()`, there is an assumption on expected format being made.  But `SUM()` cannot make that assumption when the ending points are unknown at the time of calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ScottCraner. Is there a way to lock the formatting of the sum cell so that it does not reset to "##########" every time the cell is evaluated/refreshed?

Comment: Bump for visibility.